# Solving geometric problem

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I want to find the coordinates of the $p$ point and $\beta$ angle in the following figure. The point is defined by the angle $\alpha$, the positions of the $a$ point, and the radius of the circle $r$, so the **known** variables are:

- $a$ - Coordinates
- $r$ - Radius
- $\alpha$ angle

And the **unknown** variables

- $p$ coordinates
- $\beta$ angle

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O(0,0), A(a,0)$ where $a\lt 0$.

Now consider $\triangle{OAP}$. Note that $\angle{PAO}=\pi-\alpha,\angle{OPA}=\pi-\beta-(\pi-\alpha)=\alpha-\beta$.

By the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), 
$$\frac{r}{\sin(\pi-\alpha)}=\frac{-a}{\sin(\alpha-\beta)}$$
Hence, we have
$$\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{-a}{r}\sin(\pi-\alpha)$$
So,
$$\alpha-\beta=\arcsin\left(\frac{-a}{r}\sin(\pi-\alpha)\right),$$
i.e.
$$\beta=\alpha-\arcsin\left(\frac{-a}{r}\sin(\pi-\alpha)\right)$$

Then, finally, note that we can write $P(r\cos(\pi-\beta),r\sin(\pi-\beta))$.

Comment: thank you very much I had not noticed the relationship between the angles $\angle{OPA}=\pi-\beta-(\pi-\alpha)=\alpha-\beta$.